# Binding object instance to widget instance

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm currently developing a widget for android.

The widget have some settings and I'm currently managing them with static members which means that all instances of the widget that the user creates share these settings.

The reason why I do this is because I can't figure out how to bind an instance of an object to the widget instance. The instance(s) of my AppWidgetProvider doesn't seem to be it.

Basically, I want to know what the 'standard' way to bind settings and other data to the widget instance is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to implement an Activity to manage the settings for your Widget. Have a look at Creating an App Widget Configuration Activity [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)